# Redirecting both third level and second level domains to directories on localhost

Tags: regex, .htaccess, dns, localhost

With the help of Acrylic DNS proxy a set up my localhost in a way that any address with toplevel domain "l" (example.l) is redirected to localhost. But I would like to open specific folder based on second level domain (example.l -> localhost/example)
I think the solution could be in htaccess file which would be located in root directory (C:\wamp\www\ in my case).

I found some code for subdomains and changed it a little so it would work in my case:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.l
RewriteRule ^$ /$1 [L]
```

It works for second level domain but not transparently (example.l becomes example.l/example) and third level domains are ignored (but I think that could be fixed with another htaccess file in target directory). 
I'm total noob in regular expressions so I can't get it working properly.

Any ideas?

Btw, if I add domain into the vshost file it works fine, but evading need to do that for every domain is kinda the point of what I trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use [Named Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html), not `mod_rewrite`.

This is a slightly complicated issue, as it depends on the way your system is configured, your OS, and the version of Apache you are running.

In general, however, it basically requires enabling named virtual hosts in your `http.conf`, then adding specific configurations that point to different directories for each host, which looks like this:

```
# Enabled Named Virtual Hosts
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Set up one host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.l
    ServerAlias *.example.l
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/example"
</VirtualHost>

# Add another
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName other.l
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/other"
</VirtualHost>
```

In a production system, such as one running on a Linux OS, you'd usually maintain a separate `.conf` for each domain to make it easier.

*Edit: I'm not a Windows user, so I'm not 100% on the correct directory separator format.  I changed it to match examples I found online.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I wrote - I did what you're suggesting and it works, but it is exactly what I want to avoid - the need to set up each new domain in conf files...